# EKS Private Cluster Failing to create using eksctl yaml

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

While trying to create EKS cluster (placing nodegroups in private subnets) and the EKS Controlplane (Public and Private), using the below yaml file (eksctl) I get the below error. ALSO, post executing the command, the "aws sts get-caller-identity" get hung. The EC2 machine where I execute the eksctl yaml is bind with a role having Admin policy.

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: mydatta-fulleks
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.25"

privateCluster:
  enabled: true

vpc:
  id: vpc-0d31c6395248b8433
  subnets:
    private:
      us-east-1a:
        id: subnet-00cb7da5daec56f72
      us-east-1b:
        id: subnet-03ba080c3fd9e6d38

managedNodeGroups:
- name: mydatta-eks-ng1
  privateNetworking: true
  instanceType: t3.small
  desiredCapacity: 1
  labels:
    action: mydatta
```

The error is,

```
2023-04-15 02:18:08 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-mydatta-fulleks-cluster"
2023-04-15 02:18:38 [!]  1 error(s) occurred and cluster hasn't been created properly, you may wish to check CloudFormation console
2023-04-15 02:18:38 [ℹ]  to cleanup resources, run 'eksctl delete cluster --region=us-east-1 --name=mydatta-fulleks'
2023-04-15 02:18:38 [✖]  getting stack "eksctl-mydatta-fulleks-cluster" outputs: operation error EC2: DescribeSubnets, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 10.0.13.173:443: i/o timeout
```

After the error, I try to check the role identity which gets hung,

```
[root@ip-10-0-214-70 concepts]# aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

When you set PrivateCluster=true you have to create VPC endpoints for the services that EKS depends on like EC2, ECR, and so on. See the [documentation](https://eksctl.io/usage/eks-private-cluster/) for additional information.

Comment: hi Jeremy, I see that the VPC endpoints are automatically created by eksctl, but later I realised that the VPC end points security groups needs Inbound rule (allow VPC subnet range with port 443) for worker node registration.  Cant this be done by eksctl itself?

Comment: @kishoreram I'm not sure if eksctl configures SG rules for VPC endpoints. The documentation says:

```
These VPC endpoints are essential for a functional private cluster, and as such, eksctl does not support configuring or disabling them. However, a cluster might need private access to other AWS services (e.g., Autoscaling required by the Cluster Autoscaler). These services can be specified in privateCluster.additionalEndpointServices, which instructs eksctl to create a VPC endpoint for each of them.
```